# System button in localized iPhone app are in random language

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

For some reason, the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone (button which says "Done") appears in random language (mostly Russian and sometimes Chinese) in my app. I've made sure that the device's language is English.

Would be great if anyone has a clue as to why this happens.

Here is a screenshot of the button. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to `en` from `en_GB`. Strange but solved the problem. Would be great if anyone could explain the problem.